# How are a project's NuGet dependecies packaged when the project itself is to be packaged?

Tags: c#, nuget

**Background** : I have a Logging Class which is an abstraction layer for NLog. It's was using NLog v1.0.0.505 initially when the class was written, and now we upgraded NLog to v4.4.12 with some updates in the class as well.

Some of the running applications were targeted to get this updated class, while the remaining were to continue using the older version. Now we're trying to implement this smoothly by using NuGet to create and manage versions of this class as a dependency for other projects. However, here is we got a bit stuck :

**Problem** : The NuGet package itself doesn't contain the respective NLog version, it just contains the built DLL of the class, that's all. So how can one be ever sure that a particular version of that is using the desired version of NLog ?

This can be generalized to any project with multiple NuGet dependencies as well.

**What I've tried** : 
Created these packages locally anyway and tried to add them to projects. The only thing added are simply the single DLLs, nothing else, no NLog, which has only aggravated to my confusion.

Comment: NuGet packages contain metadata saying what their dependencies are - assuming they're packaged correctly. So when you install one package, it will install any packages it depends on.

Comment: I do believe they are packaged correctly to Logging project. Restore packages etc options always work well, the builds are always smooth. I've also doubled checked the process to create packages, and am sure about that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Nuget package will contain a `.nuspec` file that indicates the dependencies it has. Since a `nupkg` file is really just a renamed zip file, you can open it up and take a look inside. If we pick a random package from Nuget, for example [GraphQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GraphQL/), we can see the `GraphQL.nuspec` inside contains a `<dependencies>` item and if we pick on the `targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0"` section, it looks like this:

```
<group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
  <dependency id="GraphQL-Parser" version="3.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
  <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
  <dependency id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
  <dependency id="System.Reactive.Core" version="3.1.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
  <dependency id="System.Reactive.Linq" version="3.1.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
</group>
```

Note the version of the packages is also specified here. These versions all indicate they will work with the one given and anything *greater*. If you needed to specify an exact version, you can surround the number with square brackets, e.g. `[10.0.3]`

You can see the various ways a version can be specified [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards).

Comment: Humph! Thanks, this makes sense, but is there any way to do this via CLI or something ? Or we've to add this manually ?

Comment: Well you have a Nuspec file now, you can edit that and use it to create your next Nuget package.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently, the Nuspec in .nupkg did already have dependencies mentioned, just that they were by default set to >= specifier. I edited it to match exact and voila, things are happening the way I wanted them to. Probably means have to apply exact versioning to packages.config as well. Thanks!

Comment: Note you could possibly use the `[...]` notation in your csproj file.

Comment: @sakshamsaxena if you migrate your project to an SDK-style csproj, then you don't need your own nuspec file. `dotnet pack` or `msbuild /t:pack` will create one for you, including using the same version of dependencies from your csproj, so you don't need to edit both your project and nuspec every time you upgrade.